# How can I use Authorize attributes in HttpTrigger of Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

Our system is role based and makes a lot of use of the `Authorize` attribute

In our App Services we use the code below to set this up:

```cs
public void ConfigureAuth(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    if (Configuration.GetValue<bool>("UseLoadTest"))
    {
        app.UseMiddleware<ByPassAuthMiddleware>();
    }

    app.UseAuthentication();
}
```

How can I do this with an Azure function Http Trigger?

There is no `UseAuthentication()` method on `IFunctionsHostBuilder`.

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
}
```

I'm using .NET Core 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Functions doesn't have such an attribute currently. [This issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1284) tracks the work going in to support Filters for Functions but this is still in preview.

Based on the above preview feature, looks like this is one library - [dark-loop/functions-authorize](https://github.com/dark-loop/functions-authorize) - that adds support for this.

Answer (score 0):

I started using Middleware for this: Took inspiration from this article:
https://jinalkumarpatel.hashnode.dev/azure-functions-middleware-part-2-authentication-middleware

Create the middleware:

```
public class BearerAuthenticationMiddleware
    : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
    private readonly ILogger<BearerAuthenticationMiddleware> logger;

    public BearerAuthenticationMiddleware(ILogger<BearerAuthenticationMiddleware> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }
    public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (context.IsHttpTriggerFunction())
        {
            var headers = context.BindingContext.BindingData["Headers"]?.ToString();
            var httpHeaders = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<HttpHeaders>(headers);
            if (httpHeaders?.Authorization != null &&
                httpHeaders.Authorization.StartsWith("Bearer"))
            {
                //Validation logic for your token. Here If Bearer present I consider as Valid.
                if (httpHeaders.Authorization.Contains("admin"))
                {
                    // Originally based on token get user role.
                    // Put into context.Items so it will be used by next middleware.
                    context.Items.Add("UserRole", "Admin");
                }
                await next(context);
            }
            else
            {
                await context.CreateJsonResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, new { Message = "Token is not valid." });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Register the middleware:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(configure=>
            {
                // other middleware also configure following way.
                // It will execute in same order it is configured over here.
                configure.UseMiddleware<SimpleMiddleware>();
            })
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```